Stationary process from composition of random variable $X$ and measure-preserving mapping $T$
Let $T$ be a measure-preserving mapping on $(\Omega, \mathscr{A}, \mathbb{P})$, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(T^{-1}(A)) = \mathbb{P}(A)$ for every $A \in \mathscr{A}$.
Let $X$ be a random variable from $(\Omega, \mathscr{A}, \mathbb{P})$ to the measurable set $(S, \mathcal{S})$.
Cleary all $X \circ T^n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, are equally distributed, but not necessarily independent. How can you show that
$$ Z := (Z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0},$$
where $Z_n = X \circ T^n$, is a strictly stationary process?

Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Please let me know why the question is so bad, and I will delete it right away.

Stationary process does not require that the random variables $Z_n = X\circ T^n$ be independent.  If $T$ is measure preserving, then the process is stationary.  (I did not downvote the question.)

Yes, but is it that obvious?

Oh, dear, now I get it. It is obvious, if one takes the right definition of a measure-preserving mapping, which is P(T^-1(A)) = P(A).

I'm glad you see how to prove it now :-). Your original post mentioned "Cleary all $∘^$, $∈ℕ_0$, are equally distributed".  I thought you just needed clarification on the definition.  It can be confusing.  Sometimes, you will see statisticians and probabilists write that a sequence $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ is i.i.d. which stands for independent and identically distributed.  To get independent, more is required than measure preserving.  If the transformation is Bernoulli, then the sequence $X_n = f\circ T^n$ will be i.i.d. for certain functions $f$ but not all $f$.  Keep the questions coming.
